# OpenBSD 5.6 / fvwm2 / xterm missing UTF-8 support

Tags: openbsd, xterm, unicode

If I log on from a RHEL 6.5/GNOME notebook via SSH using gnome-terminal to an OpenBSD install, the UTF-8 support is OK.

But if I use OpenBSD / fvwm2 / xterm locally, not via SSH, then it just misses the UTF-8 support. I wanted to write: "árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép", I got this:

[image]

opening it with vi I got this:

[image]

When the installer asked me to select language, I choosed "HU", the "árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép" is a usual test..

**Question:** How can I enable UTF-8 support to the xterm?

Comment: What is your `LANG` variable set to? Did you start `xterm` with `-u8`? The character code points shown are consistent with ISO-8859-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the FAQ, especially http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq8.html#locales, where it says:

> If logging in via xdm(1) add a line such as
>
> ```
> export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
> ```
>
> to `~/.xsession` before starting the window manager (see the section on customizing X for details). This example enables the Unicode (UTF-8) character set and will also cause applications such as xterm(1) to enable UTF-8 mode by default.

There also is [uxterm(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=uxterm&sektion=1), a wrapper around xterm that allows you to use UTF-8 without changing your locale.